# Change Project name in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

I'm trying to change the name of my project in webstorm.

I have looked at [this](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5304120?tstart=0) answer on their developer forums, but it does not work for this version (Webstorm 7). Changing the contents of `.idea/.name` does not change the name displayed in bold in the project folder view. I searched the `.idea` folder for instances of the old project name and replaced them across various configuration files like `modules.xml` and `PROJECTNAME.iml`. There are quite a few. I must have missed one because I couldn't open the project after that :)

My solution was to blow away the `.idea/` folder and open the directory again, creating a new project.

Is there a better way to change a project name?

Comment: Hit cmd+R (or ctrl+R I guess) while highlighting the top level dir in the project tree. It shows a popup whether you want to rename the dir or the project name.

Comment: I couldn't get the keyboard shortcut to work, but rightclick>refactor>rename>rename project worked. Thanks @bagonyi. Wanna answer it so I can check this off?

Comment: WebStorm has the same option as PhpStorm, documented here: [Renaming Projects - Help | PhpStorm - JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/renaming-projects.html)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Hit cmd+R (or ctrl+R I guess) or Right click / Refactor / Rename while highlighting the top level dir in the project tree.
It shows a popup whether you want to rename the dir or the project name.

Comment: When I do both (rename project and directory), I get errors when I restart Webstorm: `Cannot load module file '/.../.idea/oldname.iml':
File '/.../.idea/oldname.iml' does not exist. Would you like to remove module 'oldname' from the project?`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for (May 2020)

Answer (score 7):

If you are struggling to rename your project in the IDE you can just rename the **.iml** in the **.idea** folder to the desired name. e.g ./idea/myProject.iml -> ./idea/myRenamedProject.iml You should close Webstorm first. I can confirm this work on OSx. I've not tried it on another operating system.

Comment: This doesn't work in 2019 versions of PhpStorm on Mac

Comment: @famouspotatoes dont forget to change the path in modules.xml

Answer (score 2):

I just delete the .idea folder from File Explorer (Finder in OSX), rename the root folder of the project, and **then** open up the project in WebStorm. WebStorm will regenerate the .idea folder according to the new root folder name.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem with renaming a project in PhpStorm. There was no popup window as @bagonyi mentioned. Changing from Project Files to Project has helped. I guess it will be the same in WebStorm.

[image: Rename a project in phpstorm]