Where to rename these in the WebStorm Git remotes screen
I want to rename the "angular" and "cloudmodule" to have "src" in front of it, but the edit button only lets you edit the actual remote name "origin" and not the circled parts. I need this for some reasons surrounding attaching subrepositories and having some with the same name albeit different things entirely.

From what I already tried, I think it's somewhere in the configs of the project names that are attached but I can't figure out where. Weirdly enough the eticket one went well directly, but the other two did not.

What kind of thing are angular, clouldmodule and src\eticket?

What did you do for eticket that went well?

The ones in the screenshots are modules or dependancies @mkrieger1 there is also 2 more which are also named angular and eticket but in a different folder as main projects.

I did the exact same for all 7 opens. the original project, then the projects angular and e-ticket, and afterwards the other 3 in the screenshot. somehow the e-ticket one does perfectly what I need, I would expect the angular one to do the same as they are identical in structure. that the cloud-module doesn't do it I could see happening.

Yes, and what is that exact same thing that you did 7 times?

step 1: open a project by just file -> open project |
step 2 - 7: file open project -> dialog -> attach |
Sorry if this answer sounds dumb but that is all I did.

Does this mean that angular, cloudmodule and src\eticket are "projects" with those names? Then could you not edit each project and change its name from bla to src/bla? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478735/change-project-name-in-webstorm

So, for whoever has some weird problem like mine. I found a "solution" or workaround depending on your view.
Open both folders where the doubling names exist as projects to generate the .idea file and link the sub-projects/sub-git repositories in those Webstorm instances. Then edit a file with like a spacebar ( it can be git ignored file as long as its in there somewhere ), close the projects down, open the main project and since both folders should be opened then as well the git history for all of them  should be accessible in 1 instance of Webstorm. This also works for PHPstorm and Pycharm, haven't checked other stuff.
This was the solution that worked for me without renaming anything.
